# Avoid dynamic allocations with std::map

Tags: c++, memory-management, stdmap

I am working on a system with strict timing requirements. I have an interface into the following component:

```
void Component::Foo(std::map<unsigned char, unsigned long>& data);
```

The `data` map is being generated by consuming an array from a thread with a faster loop time. The map is then only filled with the data that is currently "active".

```
unsigned long dataArray[MAX_DATA_SIZE];
ConsumeDataArray(dataArray);

std::map<unsigned char, unsigned long> dataMap;
for(int Index = 0; Index < MAX_DATA_SIZE; Index++)
{
    if(DataIsActive(Index))
        dataMap[Index] = dataArray[Index];
}

component->Foo(dataMap);
```

The process of adding the various entries into the map will cause dynamic memory allocations (`new`). I'm looking for a way to avoid this.

I do not have the ability to change the interface of `Component::Foo`, so I don't think that I can use a custom allocator to avoid the dynamic allocations. I'm unsure if there is any other way to accomplish this.

Comment: `std::map<>` takes an allocator type (as every standard library container does)?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ "I do not have the ability to change the interface of Component::Foo, so I don't think that I can use a custom allocator to avoid the dynamic allocations."

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Changing the allocator type changes the type of the map, no? I can't change the interface into `Component::Foo`

Comment: @jaggedSpire You seem to be right. Then that's going to be impossible to work around.

Comment: I'd be surprised by if you have meaningful performance problems caused by a `map` where the absolute maximum size of the `map` is 256 `unsigned long` values... (possibly lower if `MAX_DATA_SIZE` is less than 256). I mean, you could use `insert`/`emplace_hint` to optimize slightly (you're inserting in key order, so the "hint" can always be `dataMap.end()`), but unless you're performing this task constantly, it seems unlikely that it would be more expensive than any of the actual work you're doing.

Comment: @ShadowRanger The map is regenerated every `5ms`. It is true that the dynamic allocations are less of an impact than the processing than is then performed by `Component` on the map, but there was still a desire to avoid them, if possible.

Comment: So - you are afraid that you will miss reading some data? or you will make `thread with a faster loop time` work slower? Maybe you should queue your consumed data and then in separate thread pass them further to your `components->foo`. I am not sure if this aproach would be faster than extra allocation, you would have to profile your code.

Comment: I've thought of a way that could eliminate most of the memory reallocations, but as it utilizes Undefined Behavior (by changing the const key in a map value), I am hesitant to actually show it.